# I would like the Contact on Case to be set to the Created by ID. Cannot be done with WFR or PB. Any ideas?

Tags: trigger, automation

The Contact on the Case Object is a lookup(user) I don't want my internal users to have to find their name when creating an internal case, how can I make it so that the CreatedById auto populates the ContactID with the same name?

Comment: welcome to SFSE.  Case.ContactId always points to a Contact; not a user; Case.OwnerId points at a user or queue. Please clarify your intent using [edit]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logged on UserId to be assigned to CreatedById. Because during case creation, this Logged on UserId will be CreatedById.

Comment: They're asking about populating Contact with the value of Created By.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question & updated the answer, thanks